# How to access services display view in Postman?

Tags: 7, views, services

I have used Services view display in views. If I give this url(http://ram.sample.dev/newapi/books) in the browser its showing me the results of the created view.

But same url if I try in postman **it says couldn't find the controller**. Here books is the resource name which I have created in views. I have tried using the below samples but still I got the same issue.

```
http://ram.sample.dev/newapi/books

http://ram.sample.dev/newapi/views/book_search
```

following patterns like this :

```
http://example.com/<endpoint path>/<resource name>

http://example.com/<endpoint path>/views/<view name>
```

How should I access the url for services display view in the postman ? Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Make sure you have `GET` [selected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ZHGt.jpg)

Comment: Services Views is now unsupported, I'd recommend switching over to the Views Datasource's sub module called Views JSON.